# Regex - distinguishing between very similar substrings using the substring itself

Tags: python, regex, text, python-3.10

I know the title is rather confusing, but this is a hard problem to formulate simply. Hopefully this does have a solution and is the result of me being quite new to the world of regex.

I am trying to parse some text from a chemistry book and transform it into a JSON, but i'm having trouble dividing the text by its main identifier. All of this is being done on a Python 3.10 environment.

Consider the following string:

```
0047 Heptasilver nitrate octaoxide
[12258-22-9] Ag NO
7 11
(Ag O ) .AgNO
3 4 2 3
Alone, or Sulfides, or Nonmetals
The crystalline product produced by electrolytic oxidation
of silver nitrate (and possibly as formulated) detonates
feebly at 110°C. Mixtures with phosphorus and sulfur
explode on impact, hydrogen sulfide ignites on contact,
and antimony trisulfide ignites when ground with the salt.
Mellor, 1941, Vol. 3, 483–485
See other SILVER COMPOUNDS
See related METAL NITRATES
0048 Aluminium
[7429-90-5] Al
Al
HCS 1980, 135 (powder)
Finely divided aluminium powder or dust forms highly
explosive dispersions in air [1], and all aspects of pre-
vention of aluminium dust explosions are covered in 2
US National Fire Codes [2]. The effects on the ignition
properties of impurities introduced by recycled metal used
to prepare dust were studied [3]. Pyrophoricity is elimi-
nated by surface coating aluminium powder with poly-
styrene [4]. Explosion hazards involved in arc and flame
spraying of the powder were analyzed and discussed [5],
and the effect of surface oxide layers on flammability
was studied [6]. The causes of a severe explosion in
1983 in a plant producing fine aluminium powder were
analyzed, and improvements in safety practices discussed
[7]. A number of fires and explosions involving aluminiumdust arising from grinding, polishing, and buffing opera-
tions were discussed, and precautions detailed [8] [12]
[13]. Atomized and flake aluminium powders attain
See other METALS
See other REDUCANTS
0049 Aluminium-cobalt alloy (Raney cobalt alloy)
[37271-59-3] 50:50; [12043-56-0] Al Co; Al—Co
5
[73730-53-7] Al Co
2
Al Co
The finely powdered Raney cobalt alloy is a significant
dust explosion hazard.
See DUST EXPLOSION INCIDENTS (reference 22)
0050 Aluminium–copper–zinc alloy
(Devarda’s alloy)
[8049-11-4] Al—Cu—Zn
Al Cu Zn
Silver nitrate: Ammonia, etc.
See DEVARDA’S ALLOY
See other ALLOYS0051 Aluminium amalgam (Aluminium–
mercury alloy)
[12003-69-9] (1:1) Al—Hg
Al Hg
The amalgamated aluminium wool remaining from prepa-
ration of triphenylaluminium will rapidly oxidize and
become hot upon exposure to air. Careful disposal is nec-
essary [1]. Amalgamated aluminium foil may be pyro-
phoric and should be kept moist and used immediately [2].
1. Neely, T. A. et al., Org. Synth., 1965, 45, 109
2. Calder, A. et al., Org. Synth., 1975, 52, 78
See other ALLOYS
```

This string contains information on 5 distinct compounds, which are identified by a 4 digit number at the beginning, followed by the name and then in another line the CAS unique identifier in square brackets.

The way i'm trying to divide this into separate substrings for each object is by identifying the 4 digit number which is always followed by the other identifiers and divide the text at that point.

I'm currently using this regex expression which correctly identifies the 4 digit identifiers:

`\n(\d{4})\s(?:[\s\S]*?)(?:\[\d*?-\d*?-\d*?\]|\[ *?\] [a-zA-Z]*?)`

However, this also includes a few instances of other 4 digit numbers that are not identifiers, such as dates in the body text, such as the date "1983" in the text of the Aluminum (0048) compound entry.

I have tried to use negative lookaheads with the same expression i'm using for isolating the 4 digit identifier, but none of of the ways i've tried worked. And now i'm unsure if this is even possible, or perhaps i'm overcomplicating it.

Another way to do it would be by using the CAS (in the square brackets) but that would be  worse, as there are entries with multiple or even empty CAS.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the rule for the 4 digits not to be a year? Should the line with the 4 digits always be followed by a line starting with `[` or `(`? Or should the 4 digits always start with a zero? Or should it be preceded by `See` in the line before?

Comment: Perhaps like this `^See.*\n(\d{4})\s(?:[\s\S]*?)(?:\[\d+-\d+-\d+])` https://regex101.com/r/MHk5qr/1 or like this `\n(\d{4}).*(?:\n\(.*)*\n\[\d+-\d+-\d+]` https://regex101.com/r/czf39b/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird The rule is for it to be immediately followed by the name (text with letters, numbers and symbols), a line break and a sequence of numbers encased in square brackets.

Comment: That sounds like `^(\d{4}).*\n\[\d+-\d+-\d+]` https://regex101.com/r/64EMh7/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That last expression seems to be working fine for separating dates and is much simpler than what I experimented so far. The only thing it is missing is accounting for empty square brackets, but that should be easy enough to fix. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes about your pattern:

- You can omit `[a-zA-Z]*?` at the end of the pattern as it is the last part and non greedy so it will not match any characters
- parts like `\d*?-\d*?-\d*?` and `\[ *?\]` don't have to be non greedy as the specified character to be repeated can not cross the following character

If the match should always start with a newline:

```
\n(\d{4}).*(?:\n\(.*)*\n\[(?: *|\d+-\d+-\d+)]
```

**Explanation**

- `\n` Match a newline
- `(\d{4})` Capture 4 digits in *group 1*
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:\n\(.*)*` Optionally repeat matching a newline and `(` followed by the rest of the line
- `\n` Match a newline
- `\[(?: *|\d+-\d+-\d+)]` Match `[...]` where there can be either only spaces or digits with a hyphen in between

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H4RbPH/1).

If the square brackets should be directly on the next line:

```
^(\d{4}).*\n\[(?: *|\d+-\d+-\d+)]
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5M0r3Z/1).

Comment: Again, thank you so much. But one additional question if you don't mind. How would I do if the text that follows the 4 digit identifies spans over multiple lines?

Comment: @RicardoBessa Can you create an example on regex101 here with the part that you want to match and share the link here?

Comment: I found a good example of the issue, here https://regex101.com/r/RfgDCO/1

Comment: @RicardoBessa And you want to match all lines after that you mean? Until the next occurrence of 4 digits or the end of the string? Like this perhaps https://regex101.com/r/aHnjTm/1

Comment: @RicardoBessa Or like https://regex101.com/r/9jbl8h/1

Comment: No, in this case I only want to match the text between the 4 digit identifier and the first square brackets. The example I posted with the identifiers 0071 and 0072 show my issue where if i try to match multiline names, it can also catch unwanted text if there is a date

Comment: @RicardoBessa try https://regex101.com/r/cwq98i/1

Comment: Oh yeah, that seems to be working wonderfully. It is quite complex, so it will take me a bit to fully understand the logic behind it. Thank you so much for showing me how to do it!